# Merge multiple branches into a single one

Tags: git

Assuming I have branches `o1` `o2` `o3` `o4`.

They all have multiple commits where all commits in `o1` were made before `o2` which were made before `o3`, etc...

I want to create a branch `d1` which contains all commits from `o1`, `o2`, `o3` and `o4` intact. I.e. same hash identifier. You can assume that they do not conflict with each other.

The main purpose is that if they become merged to somewhere else in the project, no duplicate commits are detected (2 different commits with the same changes).

I'm puzzled trying to do this because `git merge` removes the branch after merging and it is the only thing I was able to think of and cherry-pick (if I understood right), doesn't seem to be a proper option.

Comment: Do you know that, in Git, a branch is just a "pointer" to a commit? Based on your description (*They all have multiple commits where all commits in o1 were made before o2 which were made before o3, etc...*), you could simply merge the three older branches into the most recent one using fast-forward merges.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you statements "... `d1` with all commits from `o1` ... intact, i.e. same hash ..." does not make sense. In Git a commit hash includes the history, if you create a branch with a different content/history, the hash will change.

Comment: Which branch is being removed by `git merge`? What did you try, precisely?  Something like `git checkout -b d1`, then `git merge o1 o2 o3 o4`?

Comment: @coredump Yes. I had tried that some months ago with a different work and it had made new commits for each one of them.

Comment: @brunoais I still don't really understand what your workflow was and what you wanted to achieve, and *why you think it did not work*. Could you try to replicate the example with a toy repository and/or explain the part about duplicate commits being detected? If I have multiple branches and `git merge` all at once, then I'll have a single *merge* commit, say in branch `A`. If for example `o1` is merged elsewhere (branch X), and I merge `A` and `X`, then `git` will detect that `o1` is already present in `A`. Isn't that exactly what you need? Where did things go wrong?

Comment: @coredump Yeah. I found that git is able to identify if two different commits are the same changes. I forgot about that. That should be enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can create `d1` without modifying the hashes is if you already have history that looks something like this:

```
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *
     o1             o2             o3             o4
```

That is, if everything you can reach from `o1` is also reachable from `o2`, etc. Otherwise, creating your branch `d1` will involve creating at least one new commit from an old one, with the new one having a different parent. The parent of a commit contributes to its hash, so what you want is not possible.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Seems like what I want is impossible because git's use-cases do not include this use-case due to how the hash is calculated. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Note "They all have multiple commits where all commits in o1 were made before o2 which were made before o3, etc..." doesn't imply that the history is linear, though.